# how to use snap.svg to loop through svg elements and create array of each ones path attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, svg, snap.svg

I have an svg image that has several different paths within it. How would I go about using snap to 'loop' the svg image and create an array with the ID of each element as a variable name and the path attribute of each element and the value of that array. (Eventually I would like to animate the path morphs.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="612px"
     height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="start">
    <path id="shape" d="M197.063,173.937c-34.624,8.446-44.945,28.214-37.234,56.383c-10.217,26.923-0.263,47.865,37.234,60.639
        c-27.426,18.955-33.862,37.69-36.17,56.383c55.893-14.307,98.408-8.579,131.915,10.638c31.761-17.963,45.708-39.883,45.745-64.894
        c-45.952,8.926-61.438-0.612-63.83-18.085c40.011-15.036,53.504-32.917,44.681-53.191
        C261.068,217.78,215.96,204.763,197.063,173.937z"/>
</g>
<g id="middle">
    <path id="shape_1" fill="#590E0E" d="M265.148,215.426c-34.624,8.446-113.03-13.275-105.319,14.894
        c-10.217,26.923,39.099,4.248,76.596,17.021c-27.426,18.955-73.224,81.307-75.532,100c55.893-14.307,98.408-8.579,131.915,10.638
        c31.761-17.963,45.708-39.883,45.745-64.894c-45.952,8.926-61.438-0.612-63.83-18.085c40.011-15.036,53.504-32.917,44.681-53.191
        C324.589,80.138,328.73,149.424,265.148,215.426z"/>
</g>
<g id="final">
    <path id="shape_2" fill="#146734" d="M31.106,44.149c-34.624,8.446,121.012,158.002,128.723,186.17
        c-10.217,26.923,39.099,4.248,76.596,17.021c-27.426,18.955-73.224,81.307-75.532,100c55.893-14.307,98.408-8.579,131.915,10.638
        c31.761-17.963,45.708-39.883,45.745-64.894c-45.952,8.926-61.438-0.612-63.83-18.085c40.011-15.036,53.504-32.917,44.681-53.191
        C202.381,169.062,47.715,12.327,31.106,44.149z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the selectAll method, it will bring to back an Array like Snap object (sounds like you need this rather than an array). So something like this maybe (untested).

```
var someObj = {};
var gs = s.selectAll('g');
gs.forEach(function(el) {
    var p = el.select('path');
    someObj[ el.attr('id') ] = p.attr('d');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nz2L1wag/2/)

Comment: Thanks AGAIN Ian! I'm going to try and integrate this into my project. I expect to be asking some more questions soon :)

Comment: Ian, my image has a couple of groups within groups and many of those groups each have multiple paths inside :) How would I select all the path elements within any given group?

Comment: mygroup.selectAll('path')

Comment: Thanks Ian. For anyone interested in a little more control over looping through elements you can check out my updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nz2L1wag/5/